# Why do the solutions to the derivatives of polynomials have the same x value as their peaks and valleys?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, maxima-minima

I was graphing polynomials and their derivatives, and I noticed that the local maximums and minimums of of polynomials have the same x value as it's derivative's solutions. Is this just a coincidence?

For example, the polynomial, $3x^{5}+x^{4}+0.4x^{3}+x^{2}+2$, has a peak at, $-0.555$. The derivative of that polynomial is, $15x^4+4x^3+1.2x^2+2x$. It has the solution, $x = -0.555$

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? The peaks (local max/mins) of the derivatives have the same $y$-value as the solution to what?

Comment: Giving an example would help clarify what you mean.

Comment: you may be examining a property related to the first derivative test. and it's the other way around. when $(a, f(a))$ is an extremum over a continuous interval, then $f'(a) = 0$.

Comment: @dxiv I noticed that mistake and I corrected it

Comment: Ah, so your question is "why does an extrema of $f(x)$ correspond to a root of $f'(x)$"? (this is different than your initially posed question, which was backwards).

Comment: @AaronSpeedy That's completely different from what you originally wrote. *This* question was preemptively answered in okzoomer's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344900/why-do-the-peaks-of-deratives-of-polynomials-have-the-same-y-value-as-their-solu#comment9064972_4344900) above. Also, it is very inconsiderate to change the question, especially *after* answers have been posted.

Comment: Why did you change your question? Your original example worked just fine, and while the opposite way of "normal", it is actually a phenomenon that happens from time to time.

Comment: @Arthur I found this both with the roots of the derivatives of polynomials and the roots of polynomials. I had a bad example, and then I found a good example with the roots of the derivatives of polynomials, so I changed it, and it wouldn't fit the original question so I changed the original question. I didn't think it's matter, since saw that phenomenon equally as much

Comment: These are actually very different phenomena. Like Arthur said, the situation you are describing (as it is in the question now) **always** occurs. The original only sometimes occurs under very specific conditions.

Comment: @AaronSpeedy You did not just change the example, you [changed](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4344900/revisions) the question entirely - from "*peaks of deratives* (sic) *of polynomials have the same y value as their solutions*" to "***solutions*** *of deratives of polynomials have the same* ***x*** *value as their* ***peaks***".

Comment: @dxiv I guess it matters. When I edited it I thought it didn't. I will keep this edit up though because it seems to happen far more often

Comment: @AaronSpeedy I suggest you re-read the comments and answers more thoroughly. It doesn't happen "*far more often*", it *always* happens. You still have "*why only part of the time?*" in the question $\;-\;$ you should either remove it, or add an example where (you think) it does *not* happen. Also, you should decide whether the question you meant to ask is that in the body of the post, or the title. They are closely related, but they are not the same question.

Comment: @AaronSpeedy It's good that you are exploring mathematics and identifying patterns. However, MathStackExchange has strict rules and you should not change the example you are using. While others are commenting/answering quickly, please do not feel rushed but actually take the time to carefully choose the example you want to use. That way it saves others time, you get the answer you want, and the site mods are happy.

Comment: @okzoomer Okay. I think that I'm actually done editing it now. I am extremely sorry. 
The reason I said part of the time is because it only happened at the local maximum sometimes. Sometimes it happened at the local minimum as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** The question has been changed. The following answers the new question: "Why do local extremas of a differentiable function $f(x)$ occur precisely where $f'(x)=0$?"

Suppose we have a differentiable function $f(x)$, and further suppose that $f(x)$ has a local max (or local min) at $x=c$. Then it must be that the slope of the tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x=c$ is $0$; that is, $f(x)$ has a horizontal tangent at $x=c$.

The derivative $f'(x)$ tells us the slope of the tangent line to $f(x)$ at any $x$-value we want. Therefore, it must be that $f'(c)=0$, since the we know that $f(x)$ has a tangent slope of $0$ at $x=c$.

In summary, if $f(x)$ has a local extrema at $x=c$, then $f'(c)=0$.

(However, if $f'(c)=0$, this does **not necessarily** mean that $f(x)$ has a local extrema at $x=c$; for example, $f(x)=x^3$ at $x=0$)

Answer (score 0):

It is partly coincidence, partly not.

Take a polynomial that has at least three roots, and look at three consecutive roots of that polynomial. Like your example $x^6+x^5+x^4+2x^3+x^2$ and its roots $-1, -0.6832,0$. Between the first two roots $-1$ and $-0.6832$ there must be a critical point (in this case a local minimum), and between the last two roots $-0.6832$ and $0$ there must be a critical point (in this case a local maximum).

These two critical points correspond to roots of the derivative. And between the two roots of the derivative there must be a critical point of the derivative.

So somewhere between the two critical points of the original polynomial are both a root of the polynomial and a critical point of the derivative. There is no reason these two things need to coincide (although it's entirely possible to find examples where they do), but they might often be close enough together that it's difficult to tell from visual inspection of the graph that they are different. In your example, the critical point of the derivative actually happens at $x\approx -0.7103$, not $-0.6832$.